# The current request is not a multipart request in angularJS and Spring Rest

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest

I am trying to upload file using AngularJS on client side and Spring RESTApi on server side but getting

**Error**

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.assertIsMultipartRequest(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:216)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.resolveName(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:167)

    .......

[http-bio-8080-exec-1] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

**Rest API**

Below is a simple Java Post function:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveFile(
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    return "success";
}
```

In Angular, I am using Resource service to send request.

**Chrome Developer Tool output**

```
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundarydFRgXclyfPVixdHo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Release_Notes.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain


------WebKitFormBoundarydFRgXclyfPVixdHo--
```

**Angular Service**

```
  function FileUploadService($resource) {
    return $resource('/fileUpload/:id', {}, {
        'save' : {
            method : 'POST',
            transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter) {
                var headers = headersGetter();
                headers['Content-Type'] = undefined;

                if (data == undefined) {
                  return data;
                }

                var fd = new FormData();

                var createKey = function(_keys_, currentKey) {
                  var keys = angular.copy(_keys_);
                  keys.push(currentKey);
                  var formKey = keys.shift()

                  if (keys.length) {
                    formKey += "[" + keys.join("][") + "]"
                  }

                  return formKey;
                };

                var addToFd = function(object, keys) {
                  angular.forEach(object, function(value, key) {
                    var formKey = createKey(keys, key);

                    if (value instanceof File) {
                      fd.append(formKey, value);
                    } else if (value instanceof FileList) {
                      if (value.length == 1) {
                        fd.append(formKey, value[0]);
                      } else {
                        angular.forEach(value, function(file, index) {
                          fd.append(formKey + '[' + index + ']', file);
                        });
                      }
                    } else if (value && (typeof value == 'object' || typeof value == 'array')) {
                      var _keys = angular.copy(keys);
                      _keys.push(key)
                      addToFd(value, _keys);
                    } else {
                      fd.append(formKey, value);
                    }
                  });
                };

                addToFd(data, []);

                return fd;
              }
          }
        });
  }
```

Any hint to avoid this error?

Comment: can you show your rest-servlet.xml ?

Comment: There is no such file in my project.

Comment: ok what about app-context.xml ? That should be there as you are using springs !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue is resolved by:

1) Creating a MultipartResolver bean in WebAppConfig.java as shown below:

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

2) Replacing AngularJS FileUploadService (which is using *Resource* service) with *http* as shown below:

```
$http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        });
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Method assertIsMultipartRequest from RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver class is called.

The method asserts that it is a post request and content type starts with multipart/

```
if (!"post".equals(request.getMethod().toLowerCase())) {
        return false;
}
String contentType = request.getContentType();
return (contentType != null && contentType.toLowerCase().startsWith("multipart/"));
```

Your content type, on the other hand, is

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

And an exception is thrown.

Comment: Looks like you are setting it here:
 headers['Content-Type'] = undefined;try setting that to multipart/form-data;

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

your value attribute is missing in the requestmapping it should be like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fileupload/save/{id}" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

and use this code when creating angular resource

```
$resource('fileupload/save/:id',
      {id:'1'}, {
      save: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}}
      });
```

in springBoot theres not much to configure when uploading the file.
but you can add these properties to your application property file to change the file size limits.

```
# File size limit
multipart.maxFileSize = 3Mb

# Total request size for a multipart/form-data
multipart.maxRequestSize = 20Mb
```

Comment: We are not using Spring Boot in our project. It's a maven based spring mvc project. About value attribute, at class level, I have defined it as **@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/fileUpload")**